# New vertices added to vertex group automatically

Tags: modeling

I make a vertex group containing those two edge loops.
[image]

Then I make those two loop cuts above and below.
[image]

When I select the vertex group I previously made, I see that the new edge loops are included in the vertex group.
[image]

How can I make loop cuts without adding vertices to the vertex group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there is no way to prevent new vertex assign to near vertex group, even if it's locked. This is due to the gradient vertex weight distribution.

To better understand the mechanics turn on Vertex Group Weights:

[image]